# Calculating mixed strategy equilibrium in battle of sexes

Tags: game-theory

0
down vote
favorite
In the following game, the mixed strategy equilibrium is found as player 2 playing B 3 out of 5 times and A 2 out of 5 times but I am not able to get it. Please find the mistake in the following calculation: 
                         Player 2 
                    A                      B

```
         A     3,2                    1,1
```

Player 1

```
         B     0,0                    2,3
```

Payoff for player 1 if he plays A: 3q+1(1-q)  assuming player 2 plays A with probability q. And if he plays B payoff is 0q + 2(1-q)
For an equilibrium both payoffs should equal so 3q+1(1-q)=2(1-q) which gives q=1/4 i.e. probability of player 2 playing A which is not correct.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Economics.SE. This question seems to be a homework question (and requests descriptive detail without providing us any details of what you have tried) and we have a policy against providing help for homework questions **unless** the OP shows their work and articulates the piece of the problem with which they are having difficulty. Please consider attempting this on your own and including the details (in [Latex](http://meta.economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1417/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) here.

Answer (score 4):

Your calculations are correct. If we take this game:

\begin{array}{| r | r |}
  \hline 
\hline                       
  & A& B\\
  \hline                      
A&3,2&1,1\\
B&0,0&2,3\\
  \hline 
\end{array}

then the mixed strategy probability used by the column player must make the row player indifferent: $3q+1(1-q)=0q+2(q-1)$, implying $q=1/4$.

---

From your question, I infer that you have a solution claiming that the answer should be $q=2/5$. In that case, it looks to me like there has been a typo somewhere. Indeed, if we take the following game:

\begin{array}{| r | r |}
  \hline 
\hline                       
  & A& B\\
  \hline                      
A&3,2&0,0\\
B&0,0&2,3\\
  \hline 
\end{array}

We find the mixed strategy equilibrium implies the column player using probability $q$, with $3q=2(1-q)$ so $q=2/5$.

Note that this second, modified game is symmetric (as textbook battle of the sexes games usually are), further strengthening my suspicion that the confusion has been caused by a typo in the description of the game.